# Cura Sequential Printing

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I'm trying to get a sequential print going (first time trying this) and Cura won't slice due to build volume issues. From the graphic shown, it looks like this should be sufficiently spaced out but I'm not sure what the problem is. Any tips? I've moved the objects around all over the build volume and it never changes back to "allowable".

[image]

Comment: My Ender 3v2 has a build volume of 220x220x250 but if I try an object greater than 210 mm height or width, Cura will not slice the model.

Comment: Aren't the printable objects too high with respect to the available gantry Z height. What printer is this and what are the settings for the head dimensions?

Comment: The printer is a CR-10. The Z height in the build volume is 400 mm, but when I choose the sequential print "one at a time option" it decreases the max Z height down to the top of the object (which makes sense). With the 300 x 300mm bed size, I feel like the grantry easily has enough room to maneuver and print one without any interference from the other (I assume the granty keep out zone is what the shadow indicates)

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your printer settings and report the height of the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the height of the object is larger than the free space between the gantry and the top of the first printed object, you will not be able to slice the object. The maximum printing height will reduce to the maximum available distance between the gantry rods and nozzle.

Note that the correct `Gantry Height` needs to be set in the printer properties. For instance, the UM3 I use has 60 mm free space between the gantry and the nozzle:

[image]

If you have a smaller height specified, or a taller print object os depicted in the image below, you will not be able to slice the prints (note that a 100 x100 x100 mm is scaled to 20 x20 x70 mm prints, which exceed the 60 mm):

[image]

When properly scaled below the 60 mm, i.e. to 20 x20 x50 mm print objects, you'll see that you are able to slice the objects:

[image]

Slice preview:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It turns out the model height was 25 mm, which was exactly equal to the gantry height and if I shave 0.1 mm off the model it works.

Comment: @Asterlux Glad it works! Note that shaving it not necessary, you can also lower the print through the plate, or scale the Z.